# How to install Redis-Server 6.0.1 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: database, redis

I have Redis version 5.0.7 in my system, is there any command to update to 6.0.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the **[redis-server](https://redis.io/download)** page:

Download, extract and compile Redis with (you have of course to install via apt the build-essential and wget packages):

```
wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-6.0.3.tar.gz
tar xzf redis-6.0.3.tar.gz
cd redis-6.0.3
make
```

The binaries that are now compiled are available in the src directory. Run Redis with:

```
src/redis-server
```

You can interact with Redis using the built-in client:

```
$ src/redis-cli
redis> set foo bar
OK
redis> get foo
"bar"
```

Comment: Can we simply copy the binaries redis-* to other nodes and create a cluster or we need to compile it in every server?

Answer (score 5):

for redis version 6.2.x, the instruction from redis download page https://redis.io/download section `From the official Ubuntu PPA`

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:redislabs/redis
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install redis
```

I believe the PPA is maintained by redis team.